# MongoDB list projection of subfield

Tags: mongodb, projection

With SQL analogy, I need to `SELECT root.subfield1.subfield2 FROM collection`, that produces *a list of subfield2* ...
Using a Example: import this [datapackage.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/language-codes/master/datapackage.json) by

`mongoimport -d lang_db -c lang_meta  datapackage.json  --jsonArray`

and work at terminal with `mongo` command:

**`db.lang_meta.find({},{"resources.schema.fields.name":2})`**

the result is one array element (`.count()`=1) with subfields containing the names, not a list of names.

---

### DUMPS

*obtained:*

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("56011be94564569fc920eda4"),
    "resources": [{
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
            "name": "alpha2"
        }, {
            "name": "English"
        }]
    }
    }, {
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
            "name": "alpha3-b"
        }, {
            "name": "alpha2"
        }, {
            "name": "English"
        }]
    }
    }, {
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
            "name": "alpha3-b"
        }, {
            "name": "alpha3-t"
        }, {
            "name": "alpha2"
        }, {
            "name": "English"
        }, {
            "name": "French"
        }]
    }
    }, {
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
            "name": "lang"
        }, {
            "name": "langType"
        }, {
            "name": "territory"
        }, {
            "name": "revGenDate"
        }, {
            "name": "defs"
        }, {
            "name": "dftLang"
        }, {
            "name": "file"
        }]
    }
    }]
}
```

*wanted:*

> "alpha2","English","alpha3-b", "alpha2", "English" ...

Comment: use [distinct](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) like this  `distinct("resources.schema.fields.name")`

Comment: @Yogesh Thanks!! and, ops, sorry, I can delete below... I was looking for in the guide, and not see your answer while answering... 2 minutes ...

Answer (score 0):

I find the command!! it is not `find()` :-)

`db.lang_meta.distinct("resources.schema.fields.name")`

[db.collection.distinct](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/)

---

(edit)

Ops, the "strictly correct" answer is a *list* (where repeat itens is possible) not a *set* (where no repeat occurs). See the case of `db.lang_meta.distinct("resources.mediatype")`, where the correct solution must return a list of four repeated items, not only one.

For *list* we can use `map()`... Well, suppose only one item, it  would be ...

```
db.lang_meta.find().map(function(c) { 
  return c.resources[0].schema.fields[0].name; 
});
```

but must iterate over `.resources` and over `.fields`, so

```
db.lang_meta.find().map(function(c) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i=0; i<c.resources.length; i++) 
        for (var j=0; j<c.resources[i].schema.fields.length; j++) 
             ret.push( c.resources[i].schema.fields[j].name );
   return ret;
});
```

... that is near but not the ideal (elegant) solution.

Returning to the `resources.mediatype` example, that is a better illustration to the "repeat itens",

```
db.lang_meta.find().map(function(c) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i=0; i<c.resources.length; i++) 
             ret.push( c.resources[i].mediatype );
   return ret;
});
```

That produces  `"text/csv", "text/csv", "text/csv", "text/csv"` (!)
but in a array-of-array structure... not a simple array.

### Solution?

Lets do something with `db.lang_meta.find({},{"resources.schema.fields.name":1})` ...