# elegant list of repeated sub-items

Tags: mongodb

How to transform a path projection into a single array with MongoDB?

---

Using real data, importing this [datapackage.json](https://github.com/datasets/language-codes/blob/master/datapackage.json) by

`wget -c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/language-codes/master/datapackage.json`

`mongoimport -d lang_db -c lang_meta  datapackage.json  --jsonArray`

suppose that I need a list of all mediatypes used in the resources, repeating... So the simplest syntax `db.lang_meta.distinct("resources.mediatype")`, is not a solution to this propblem...

And `db.lang_meta.find({},{"resources.mediatype":1}).pretty()` not produces a single list, but a complex object,

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("56011be94564569fc920eda4"),
"resources" : [
    {
        "mediatype" : "text/csv"
    },
    {
        "mediatype" : "text/csv"
    },
    {
        "mediatype" : "text/csv"
    },
    {
        "mediatype" : "text/csv"
    }
]}
```

to reduce complexity  we can try `map()`,

```
var aux = db.lang_meta.find().map(function(c) {
    var ret = [];
    for (var i=0; i<c.resources.length; i++) 
             ret.push( c.resources[i].mediatype );
   return ret;
});
var solution = aux[0];
```

but **it is not elegant** (!)... There are a simple syntax in **mongoDB** to do this?

---

This question is related with this other [question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32716677/287948).

Answer (score 1):

Use **[$map](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** in aggregation like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate({"$project":{"resources":{"$map":{"input":"$resources","as":"el","in":"$$el.mediatype"}}}})
```

Comment: ERROR message when using `db.lang_meta.aggregate({"$project":{"resources":{"$map":{"input":"$resources","as":"el","in":"$$el.mediatype"}}}})`: exception: invalid operator '$map'
`

Comment: looks like you used old version of MongoDB check this [release note](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/)

Comment: I am at Debian Stable and db.version()=2.4.10 , you use `wget` and `mongoimport` to test your query?

Comment: @PeterKrauss `$map` support in version 2.6 and above so either you should switch to new version to test `$map`

Comment: Ops, yes ;-( ... My Debian is 8.2 (jessie) and your link say "Currently packages are only available for Debian 7 (Wheezy)"...

Comment: ... So, there are no simpler way, to do a simple projection with MongoDB?  Example: PostgreSQL 9.4 offer the JSON's [`#>>`  operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html).

Comment: in 2.4 you should go for `map` as per your question your mentioned code   or switch to new version and use power of `$map` and other new features :)