# MongoDB: Get all elements of a nested array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Is it possible to get every element which is saved in a nested array with a `find()`. I need to get a list of all elements which are saved in the cat-field of the documents.

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "title" : "title 1",
    "cat" : [
        {
            "element" : "element 1"
        },
        {
            "element" : "element 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "title" : "title 2",
    "cat" : [
        {
            "element" : "element 3"
        },
        {
            "element" : "element 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Result of this example should be - as I also need the id of the document:

```
1, element 1
1, element 2
2, element 3
2, element 4
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [elegant list of repeated sub-itens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733388/elegant-list-of-repeated-sub-itens)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try out following query with `distinct` :

```
db.collection.distinct("cat.element")
```

**EDIT:**

Then you can try out [$map](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) **as marked in duplicate question** like:

You can simply use it like :

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$project": {
    "cat": {
        "$map": {
            "input": "$cat",
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.element"
        }
    },
    "title": 1
    }
})
```

**OR**

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$project": {
    "cat": {
        "$map": {
            "input": "$cat",
            "as": "el",
            "in": "$$el.element"
        }
    },
    "title": 1
    }
}, {
    $group: {
    _id: "$_id",
    "title": {
        $first: "$title"
    },
    "cat": {
        "$first": "$cat"
    }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But then I will loose the document informations. I need these elements and the id of the document.